# Python cannot import flask_jwt_extended

Tags: python, flask

I was working with python flask for making a basic backend server but keep getting this error

```
"from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager, jwt_required, create_access_token, get_jwt_identity, get_raw_jwt
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_raw_jwt' from 'flask_jwt_extended"
```

Things i tried to rectify this:-

1. reinstalled all the imports/depedences
2. updated flask-extended-jwt
   3)saw one article to change auth/views.py file then the error changes but still there was some error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Where did you get the information to do ```from flask_jwt_extended import ... get_raw_jwt...```?  From https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html, no such method exists.

Answer (score 2):

After version 4.0.0, `flask-jwt-extended` had Renamed `get_raw_jwt` to `get_jwt`. Check your version `flask-jwt-extended` [Detail](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/v4_upgrade_guide.html#api-changes)